# Why does Google Chrome ignore a li's 'direction'?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

The following works in Firefox and IE, but in Chrome - the li's `direction` is ignored:

```
<ul class="abc">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>

.abc
{
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    direction: rtl;
}

.abc li
{
    direction: ltr;
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: Lime;
}
```

Chrome: `_____3_____2_____1`

FF & IE: `3_____2_____1_____`

Why?

Comment: try using the `dir` attribute.

Comment: @Paulie_D I don't know. But it _does_ work in FF & IE.

Comment: @DanielA.White Thanks. But it didn't help. (And would be a problem anyway, because I would have to add it every time.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because FF automatically compute `text-align:left` property to your `<li>` elements. Chrome, by default, sets it to `text-align: -webkit-match-parent;`.

If you want the same appearance, specify it on the css class:

```
.abc li
{
    direction: ltr;
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: Lime;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That solved it. I wonder, though, why does the `text-align` change one way without me explicitly changing it, and not the other way.

Comment: It's a browser behavior. If you check the Chrome debug, you will see that the default `text-align` property of li element is inherited from `user agent stylesheet`. Firefox's user agent is set to align it to the "left"

Comment: But I never set it to be rtl, I only set `direction`. What seems to happen is that Chrome 'fixes' `text-align` according to `direction` for `ul`'s but not for `li`'s. So the `li` inherits the 'corrected' `text-align` from its `ul`. (Guesswork, of course.)

Comment: Yes, possibly. the Chrome's text-align is actually `-webkit-match-parent`, so it will use the align of the `ul`